# Create a factory JSON deserializers in Jackson

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization

I have a bunch of interfaces annotated as follows:

```
@MyAnnotation(DefaultImplementation.class)
interface SomeInterface {
    ...
}
```

and an accompanying implementation

```
class DefaultImplementation implements SomeInterface {
    ...
}
```

When my ObjectMapper runs into a field of type `SomeInterface` I would like it to deserialize it as if it was a `DefaultImplementation`. That is, I would like encode the following logic in the deserialization process:

```
if (staticTypeToDeserialize.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class))
    deserializeAs(type.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class).value());
else
    fallBackOnRegularDeserialization();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have a complete answer for you. Jackson can do this through a MixIn. I'm no expert on that, but I did it recently so ... In essence, you stick type information into the JSON, then Jackson can use that type information to deserialize it the way you want.

So first, you need a mixin class that knows about the types you are going to serialize and deserialize.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyString.class, name = "mystring"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyEvent.class, name = "myevent") })
public abstract class PolymorphicMixIn {
}
```

The MyString and MyEvent class derive from the same base class in my case. So everything I stick in and out of Jackson is that one class type. Say that baseclass is MyBaseClass.

So then in your jackson class, you need to tell the object mapper about this.

```
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(MyBaseClass.class, PolymorphicMixIn.class);
```

That's pretty much it. Now you can just call objectMapper.writeValueAsString and it'll write the Jackson and stick in type information.

To read it out, just pass in the class type you are expecting:

```
MyString outputString = objectMapper.readValue(argAsString, MyString.class);
```

I hope that's enough to get you where you need to be!

Comment: Doesn't this require me to create one mixin for each interface with a `@MyAnnotaiton`? This is not desirable. I would like to easily be able to add new interfaces annotated with `@MyAnnotation`. Also, this requires me to modify the JSON representation. This is also undesirable in my setup. This is the reason I believe I need some form of factory for my deserializers (i.e. a way to create a deserializer on the fly, based on the `@MyAnnotation` annotation)